# SimpleXML looping through

Tags: php, xml

I get product data via xml like that

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <brands>
        <brand>
            <name>Spielberger Mühle</name>
            <kuerzel>SPI</kuerzel>
            <id>e3124594-1d4c-4a72-8c66-37de394fece2</id>
            <last_modified>27.04.2021 23:00:03</last_modified>
            <logo>
                <id>e3124594-1d4c-4a72-8c66-37de394fece2</id>
                <name>SPI_Spielberger Mühle_e3124594-1d4c-4a72-8c66-37de394fece2.jpg</name>
                <size>273981</size>
                <mime_type>image/jpeg</mime_type>
                <img_width>1533</img_width>
                <img_height>676</img_height>
                <last_modified>13.12.2016 12:48:02</last_modified>
            </logo>
            <url>www.spielberger-muehle.de</url>
            <adr_invb_name>Spielberger GmbH</adr_invb_name>
            <adr_invb_strasse>Burgermühle</adr_invb_strasse>
            <adr_invb_plz>74336</adr_invb_plz>
            <adr_invb_ort>Brackenheim</adr_invb_ort>
            <adr_invb_land_id>8</adr_invb_land_id>
        </brand>
    </brands>
    <producers>
        <producer>
 ....
```

and in my php (shortened to the relevant parts)

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('demo.xml');

    foreach ($xml->brands->brand as $key => $value) {

        print "Key: $key - Value: $value\n";

    }
```

If I try to loop through the brand the following happens

```
 Key: brand - Value:
```

edited because I figured I was way to verbose.

Comment: Can't you provide a test case ?

Comment: @JCH77 what do you mean by test case? a short working script that demonstrate the behavior?

Comment: "a short working script that demonstrate the behavior?" Yes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because of how SimpleXMLElement handles it's iterator. You can iterate through the element using the `get_object_vars` function.

```
foreach (get_object_vars($xml) as $key => $value) {
    print "Key: $key - Value: $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Seems right but how? I call the method with $res->$plural->$datatype ($plural is brands and $datatype = brand) or how I'm supposed to call the method to make it work?

Comment: well just a note I'm aware this call like I made in my script is weird but the way I fetch my XML from the API makes sure there is always one brand one producer or one product - just for info

Comment: Ah of course, my mistake. This is indeed a strange problem. I am looking at your demo script now.

Comment: @Michael I figured out the issue and have edited the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that SimpleXML does **not** give you arrays; all of the things you have output in the question are **objects**, and understanding how those particular objects work is key.

In particular, the object is designed to allow you to *iterate over multiple nodes with the same name*. In your particular case, there is only one `<brand>` element, but the library still lets you loop in case there's sometimes more than one:

```
foreach ( $xml->brands->brand as $brandElement )
```

This is the loop you've accidentally written; it loops once, because there is one matching element, and the key is "brand", because that's the name of that element. The actual object you wanted is the *value* in the loop.

Since you know that there is always one matching element in your case, you can directly ask for the first one:

```
$brandElement = $xml->brands->brand[0];
```

That is also implied if you access children of the element:

```
$brandName = $xml->brands->brand->name;
// short for $xml->brands[0]->brand[0]->name
```

Finally, you can get a list of all children of an element explicitly with `->children()`:

```
foreach ( $xml->brands->brand->children() as $name => $element )
// equivalent to foreach ( $xml->brands[0]->brand->children() as $name => $element )
// or foreach ( $xml->brands->brand[0] as $name => $element )
```